# Edit Not working in MVC contrib grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

i am using mvc contrib grid in that edit is not working so far i have used this coding

in view....

```
    <%= Html.Grid<Product>(Model) 
    .Columns(column => 
    {

        column.For(c => c.CategoryID); 
        column.For(c => c.SupplierID);
        column.For(c => c.ProductID);
        column.For(c => Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = c.CategoryID })).InsertAt(0).Encode(false);
        column.For(c => Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = c.CategoryID })).InsertAt(1).Encode(false);
    }) 
%>
```

in my controller i have used :

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            ProductsDataContext db = new ProductsDataContext();
            return View(db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CategoryID == id));

        }
```

here details is working in edit is not working

Comment: And by *`not working`* you mean? Start by explaining what are you trying to achieve and what is the expected behavior, then show what you've tried so far (you've already done this) and finally explain the actual result and how it differs from the expected result. Are you getting an exception? If yes, post the full stack trace, etc... I think you get the point. We cannot guess what is your scenario and what are you trying to achieve. Remember that the more details you provide, the better answers you will get. Posting a couple of code snippets and saying that it's not working is not very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should error out:

```
db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CategoryID == id)
```

Multiple Products can have the same CategoryId, so that line will error out when more than 1 Product has the same CategoryId.  I don't understand why you are querying Products, but using the CategoryId as the Key.